# Python / Pandas / PyMySQL - %s synthax

Tags: python, pandas, pymysql

I'm trying to do the following operation:

```
import pymsql
import pandas as pd

df:

     id      height_code        name          ...
1    34      123123             Jesus
2    84      3421               Heaps
3    23      45243              Ornitorrincus
...

connection=pymysql.connect(host=xxx,user=xxxx,password=xxxx,db=xxxx)

for i in df.index:
    df2=pd.read_sql("select business_id,name,color from table123 where business_id=%s;",connection) % df['id'][i]
```

The idea here is only to access a giant sql and filter table123 using only the rows where `business_id = df['id'][i]`

However, I'm getting the following error:

```
pandas.io.sql.DatabaseError: Execution failed on sql 'select business_id,nome,qualificacao_id from socio_administrador where business_id=%s;': (1064, "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '%s' at line 1")
```

So, apparently I'm having trouble with the `%s` synthax in pymsql. Tried to have a look at their manual but didn't find a nice explanation about that.

Could anybody help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have:

```
read_sql("... where business_id=%s;",connection) % df['id'][i]
```

Must be:

```
read_sql("... where business_id=%s;" % df['id'][i], connection)
```